# Monotouch: UITextField.LeftView works, RightView does not

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using the latest version of MT here. There is no `RightView` property in `UITextField`. Looks like it was forgotten to bind. Can I bind it manually?

**RESOLVED - READ TO END**

**EDIT**: Thanks to Geoff I'm geting closer. Using the `LeftView` (!) I got this code working without problems:

```
var _entry = new UITextField ();
UIButton oLeftButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
_entry.LeftView = oLeftButton;
_entry.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

Trying with RightView using the manual bindings:

```
var _entry = new UITextField ();
UIButton oRightButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_intptr (_entry.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setRightView:"), oRightButton.Handle);
// Code crashes here with a NULL ref in ObjC.
_entry.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

**AND ANOTHER EDIT:**
There is a bug in MT 3.x which will be fixed in MT4 and results in a crash when accessing RightViewMode property. The RightViewMode has to be set directly like demonstrated here.

```
var _entry = new UITextField ();
UIButton oRightButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
// Set RightView directly.
Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_intptr (_entry.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setRightView:"), oRightButton.Handle);
// Set RightViewMode directly.
Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_int (_entry.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setRightViewMode:"), (int)UITextFieldViewMode.Always);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this was missed, it will be fixed in MonoTouch 4 Alpha 3.

You can manually invoke it like such:

```
Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.intptr_objc_msgSend (textField.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("leftView")));
```

Comment: "No overload for method GetNSObect takes 2 arguments".
I tried UITextField.GetNativeField("rightView") instead but that doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, sorry, answered before my coffee.  Edited

Comment: Does not seem to work. Here's my code:
UITextField entry = new UITextField();
// This line already crashes...
entry.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
// If I comment out the line above, this one returns NULL.
UIView oRightView = Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.intptr_objc_msgSend (_entry.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("rightView"))) as UIView;

Comment: You need to set the right view at some point, you can do that with:  Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_intptr (_entry.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setRightView:"), theRightView.Handle);

Comment: See http://www.iphonedevbook.com/forum/iphone-development-questions/686-how-add-right-view-text-field.html for an objc example.

Comment: Getting closer.
UIButton oRightButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_intptr (_entry.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setRightView:"), oRightButton.Handle);
UIView oRightView = Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.intptr_objc_msgSend (_entry.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("rightView"))) as UIView;
// The UIView is not NULL - fine!
Console.WriteLine("RIGHT_VIEW: "+ (oRightView != null));
// This still crashes.
_entry.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

UITextField.set_RightViewMode in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone-3/monotouch/UIKit/UITextField.g.cs:611

Comment: I adusted my original questionas these comments are getting out of control. Please see there.

Comment: Talked to Geoff on the MT chat. It is a bug in MT. It will be fixed in MT4. There is a workaround which I added to my answer.